# iPhone "Icon already includes gloss effects = YES" - Appstore Icon still glossy in iOS 4

Tags: iphone, ios, effect

in my Info.plist I set "Icon already includes gloss effects = YES". Normally it was enough to hide the gloss effects in the appstore too. But my last two Apps I loaded up have still the glossy glow in the Apple app store. Is there a new way to hide the gloss?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I do not get the gloss effect when app is downloaded but the iTunes store does show the gloss effect.

Comment: I get the same thing. I have a ticket in with Apple Developer Support.

Answer (score 3):

Have you add the following line in your info.plist right before the `</dict>` ?

```
<key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: in my app also in the dev itunesconnect app detail it shows:
Prerendered Icon Flag :  true
in iTunes store its without glossy effect but in iTunes store with glossy effect. also i don't know what to do.

Answer (score 3):

Are you developing/running on iOS 5?
Because the new Info.plist structure for iOS 5 has a new entry with the same key (UIPrerenderedIcon) which is placed in a sub dictionary along with the icon file names. You should still include the original UIPrerenderedIcon key in the root of the Info.plist for iOS 4 and earlier.

If you are converting from an older project, simply copy the format from a new project created with the assistant. It will have the key in the right place already.

Answer (score 1):

Open the plist in source code and do

```
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>myIcon.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

This line before the

```
<key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <true/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I set “Icon already includes gloss effects = YES”
In the info.plist, search this part:

```
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>myIcon.png</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Now, add this 2 lines:

```
       <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
       <false/>
```

At the end, It must to be:

```
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>myIcon.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Info.plist file. Make sure the "Icon already includes gloss effect" boolean in that dict is set to "YES".

Then go To project Target settings tick the checkbox on Prerendered.

Answer (score -1):

it's a ITS bug. If you set the UIPrerenderedIcon to FALSE, it will set a plain icon on ITS.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a mistake by the dev